# How to call async function inside Web form/ MVC Razor Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Write(await FunctionStringAsync("name"));
}
```

Above one is Working for me but, I want to use inside Razor like

```
<%=(await FunctionStringAsync("name"))%>
or
@(await FunctionStringAsync("name"))
```

I am getting

*warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.*

*error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.*

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't want to. Ensure that your view model contains all data that you wish to display.

Comment: Dear @CodeCaster, Why not? Is it documented anywhere? As i think if we can explicitly mark page_load as async then why not control rendering? Using client script and achieve target by loading once inside controller or page_load is different thing. In my case i am using multiple if else in side razor and create tags dynamically, I don't want to repeat if else inside controller and razor again.

Comment: You cannot mark a view async, period. Razor gets compiled to a C# class that is executed, and async is not supported in it. You should not even want to use async in a view. If you need it, it's a sign that you're doing too much heavy work in the view.